# Installing Connector/Python with pip

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip

I have a windows and when I run

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

I get

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (8.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf<=4.21.12,>=4.21.1 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from mysql-connector-python) (4.21.12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
I deleted site-packages (8.2.0) and site-packages (from mysql-connector-python) (4.21.12)
and run
pip install mysql-connector-python again